# sqlalchemy delete row if not distinct

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite database created with pandas that has a table, with 6 columns.

```
Date     name      country     items      value     comment
2/2/16   ABC       USA         xxx        44        ggg
2/2/16   ABC       USA         xxx        44        ggg
2/2/16   ABC       USA         xxx        44        ggg
2/2/16   ABC       USA         xxx        44        ggg
2/4/16   GHI       UK          xxx        77        ggg
2/5/16   GHI       UK          xxx        88        ggg
2/6/16   XYZ       China       xxx        99        ggg
```

I am able to select the distinct rows based on the below code

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
meta = MetaData()
zzz = Table('This_Table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
unique_date = session.query(zzz.columns['Date'].distinct()).count()
```

But my question is, how do I delete these duplicated rows in the SQL Database?

Comment: Do realize that `distinct on column` selects one row among them pretty much **at random**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Don't quite understand what you mean. I thought `distinct` would give me only the unique dates? Leaving out the duplicated entries?

Comment: If you run distinct on on that dataset, you will have 4 dates. One of the 2/2/16 will be chosen at random.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my table to be more reflective of what I intend to do. ie: I want to delete these duplicated entries from the sqlite database.